# Which Kotlin version is officially supported by Android?

Tags: kotlin, android-api-levels

I've recently developed an application in Kotlin 1.2.10 and got an error in Android Studio:

`Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.Map#forEach`.

Referring the following code:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
map.forEach { s1: String, s2: String -> print("something") }
```

So the question is, how do I know that Kotlin methods that I use (outside Android Studio, e.g. IntelliJ) will be available on certain Android API level?

I can't find information about which Kotlin version is Android supporting (and on which API level).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Kotlin is compatible with Android as long as you

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" // or
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
```

This forEach method with a two-parameter callback is from Java 8 and it's only available since API 24. This is also the reason why below API 24 you can't

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```

What you were looking for is the Kotlin extension function which would look like this:

```
map.forEach { (key, value) -> // One parameter of type Map.Entry<String, String>
    // Do something
}
```